# Ruby Rake Mongoid List Rows in a Table

Tags: ruby, mongoid, rake

I'm new to Ruby and Rake and I'm looking to build a simple backend application that queries a Mongo DB and then runs tasks off of the results.

Here's my current code:

```
task default: %w[getProd]
require 'mongoid'

desc "Get Product named iPad from the product table"
task :getProd do
  product.where(name: "iPad")
end
```

**How can I query using Mongoid from within a Rake task?**

Comment: Using mongoid on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

My initial confusion was because I skimmed over the Mongoid doc:
https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial

After I followed the documentation I came up with the following that works outside of rails:

```
require 'mongoid'
Mongoid.load!('mongoid.yml', :development)

class Sites
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: "sites"
end

task default: %w[getYahoo]

desc "Gets Site named Yahoo"
task :getYahoo do
  puts Sites.where(name: "Yahoo").as_json
end
```

Where mongoid.yml is in the same path as the Rakefile. sites is a collection within the database specified in the configuation. Running rake without parameters works because 'getYahoo' is the default task.